# Why am I not reading the first member of the class when I point to the object with a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I'm experimenting with smart pointers and I wrote the code below:

```
struct Buffer
{
    char Data[128];
};

class SmartPtr {
    char * dataPtr;

public:
    SmartPtr(Buffer& b)
    {
        dataPtr = b.Data;
    }

    ~SmartPtr()
    {
        cout << "desctructor called" << endl;
    }

    void operator=(Buffer & b)
    {
        dataPtr = b.Data;
    }

    char*& operator*()
    {
        return dataPtr;
    }
};
```

I though that when using a pointer of the same type as the type of the first member of a class I can access that member.
What I'm trying to do is accessing `dataPtr` by getting the address of the object `p`.
I'm expecting `p` and `dataPtr` to have the same address.

The following code prints garbage.

```
static Buffer buff;

int main(void)
{
    strcpy(buff.Data, "Hello world");

    SmartPtr p = buff;
    char* s = (char*)&p;
    cout << "Data: " << s << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Data: Ç☺┴─≈
desctructor called
```

If I change that to a double pointer I get the expected result

```
static Buffer buff;

int main(void)
{
    strcpy(buff.Data, "Hello world");

    SmartPtr p = buff;
    char** s = (char**)&p;
    cout << "Data: " << *s << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Data: Hello world
desctructor called
```

Is it because with a single pointer I dereference the address of the actual pointer as a variable instead of the address it contains?

Comment: You should not cast a struct to its first member. It is error prone. For example, it would break if someone add an extra member before without compiler warning.  Add a function that return the pointer if it is what you want. Even making `dataPtr` public would be better than such cast. By the way, you should also use C++ cast. As normally `reinterpret_cast`  should be avoided, you would have known that you were casting incompatible types...

Comment: To answer the question at the end of your question -- yes, you are correct.  Your `cout << "Data: " << s << endl;` line in the first example is trying to print out the bytes of a pointer as if they were the ASCII bytes of a NULL-terminated string, hence the garbage characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code, you are taking the address of `p` (and thus the address of `p.dataPtr`), casting it to `char*`, and then printing it as-is.  So, `operator<<` is misinterpreting the raw memory of `p` itself as-if it were a null-terminated string, which it is not, so you get garbage.

In the second code, you are taking the address of `p` (and thus the address of `p.dataPtr`), casting it to `char**`, dereferencing it to access its value as a `char*`, and then printing that.  So, `operator<<` is printing the data that `p.dataPtr` is pointing at as a null-terminated string, which it is, so you get the correct result.